# battle with two combobox events in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selectionchanged

I have two `ComboBoxes` in WPF. I have a bit crisis with their events. When I use the event of `ComboBox1_SelectionChanged`, I want to get two `selectedValues`, but `ComboBox2` doesn't get value because there is no event How to solve this? Any suggestion?

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (ComboBox1.SelectedValue == "Shoe" && ComboBox2.SelectedValue == "Nike")
   {
      //TODO
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow. You should be able to query for the selected value of any combobox whenever you want; you don't have to listen to the event.

Comment: okay...can you show me your code example, please!! thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, my code example probably would have been exactly what you posted. What exactly is going wrong? Have you placed a debugger breakpoint and checked that the values are what you expect? Is the code in your `//TODO` not running? Have you _tried_ to run the code you posted?

Comment: What wrong is : when i select "Shoe", the event will be fired and it will get value "Dinner". But when I select both "Shoe" and "Nike", there is no SelectedValue of "Nike" so it wont pass if statement. hope u understand....

Comment: How can you select the values at the same time? Fastest mouse fingers in the west? Have you double-checked that you're inserting the correct label/values into the combo boxes when you build your GUI?

Comment: yeah but you know what i mean. Sorry my english bad. I mean when I select BOTH "Shoe" from ComboBox1 and "Nike" from ComboBox2, i only get SelectedValue "Shoe" but not "Nike" so it wont pass the if statement.

Comment: You should wire up the same event handler to the Combobox2.
The event handler will then be fired once each combobox changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi user1358072  I think you should set SelectedIndex="0" of combobox2 in xaml code.

It is working on my side .

If you want to handle event for both combo box create event handler for both. and set

SelectedIndex="0" for both.

I think it will useful for You

Comment: good idea... i am not sure how to create event handler for both. maybe you dont mind showing me your code example so that i would get a picture in my mind. thanks so much for your time :)

Comment: private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == "Shoe" && comboBox2.SelectedValue == "Nike")
            {
                //TODO
            }
        }
        private void comboBox2_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == "Shoe" && comboBox2.SelectedValue == "Nike")
            {
                //TODO
            }
        }